# Text after hyphen ( - ) is not retrieved from Database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I am using the following code for autocomplete facility:

Source:

```
  $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtSearch]").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/SrchProduct.aspx/GetProducts") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },

            minLength: 1
        });
```

Code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetProducts(string prefix)
{
    List<string> products = new List<string>();
    ConnDB c = new ConnDB(); 

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "select Product from Product where Product like '%' + @SearchText + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
            cmd.Connection = c.sqlconn;
            c.sqlconn.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    products.Add(string.Format("{0}", sdr["Product"]));
                }

                c.sqlconn.Close();


    return products.ToArray();
}
```

This works good to make textbox works as the following:

[image: autocomplete works fine]

The problem is happening with items that have hyphen (-) in their text, for example:

E133 Brilliant Blue FCF Lake 10-14

I got : E133 Brilliant Blue FCF Lake 10

and E133 Brilliant Blue FCF Lake 14-18

I got : E133 Brilliant Blue FCF Lake 14

The function retrieves text up to the (-). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: label: item.split('-')[0],
val: item.split('-')[1]

These lines might cause you the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
return {
       label: item.split('-')[0],
       val: item.split('-')[1]
   }
```

to

```
return {
       label: item
   }
```

I don't know why but you are splitting the results of your query to make your dropdowns show the part before the hyphen, but have the value of the part after it (probably and ID).